# What is the purpose of the light blue rectangle positioned in same column as the breakpoints in the Visual Studio interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I accidentally pressed some keys in Visual Studio 2010 and ended up with an icon I never saw before placed where the breakpoints are usually placed:

[image]

Anyone can tell me what it does and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are bookmarks.

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh.aspx

and here:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vipul/archive/2006/01/20/Visual-Studio-Bookmarks.aspx

Excerpt from the documentation:

> The **Bookmarks** window is a handy companion tool to the **Code Editor**. You
>   can mark lines in your code files with bookmarks and then organize
>   these bookmarks into virtual folders. This enables you to open files
>   and navigate directly to the lines marked simply by clicking entries
>   in the **Bookmarks** window.
>
> Common procedures for using bookmarks appear below.
>
> In most Visual Studio programming languages, you can also create **Task
>   List** shortcuts and comments. As with bookmarks, you can click on any
>   entry in the Task List to open a file and jump to the line of code
>   marked. For more information, see How to: Use Task List Shortcuts and
>   How to: Create Task List Comments.
>
> To create or remove a bookmark using the Bookmarks window
>
> 1. Open a source code file for editing in the Code Editor.
> 2. Place the insertion point on the line of code you want to bookmark.
> 3. On the View menu, select Bookmark Window.
>
>    The Bookmarks window is displayed. It can be docked along any
>      convenient edge of the IDE. The list of bookmark entries includes an
>      entry for the newly bookmarked line in the active document.
> 4. Click the Toggle a bookmark button in the Bookmarks window.
>
>    A bookmark token appears in the Indicator margin of the Code Editor
>      next to the selected line. Click the button again to remove the
>      bookmark.

Comment: It's funny, i went into the Edit menu after asking the question and there it was the icon :) I asked too soon. Thanks for answer! :)